# R Studio Server cannot access Repository

Tags: r, server, rstudio, redhat

Hi I'm new in infrastructure and still learning. I would like to ask a question:

If there are 2 servers (both using Red Hat), 1 for RStudio and 1 for MiniCran. MiniCran server has full access to internet, but not for RStudio. RStudio Server can ping to MiniCran Server. But, when I tried to install packages in RStudio Server from MiniCran Server *(All packages are already in MiniCran Server.)*. The error is `Unable to to access index repository http://xxx.xx.xx/minicran/src/contrib`. 
But if I tried to install in MiniCran server using local file, it can be installed.

Is that related firewall or anything else? 
Thanks so much in advance for anyone who wants to help give a suggest or answer.

Comment: Does the minicran server host a http service such as apache?

Comment: @wush978 yes it has :)